# Shifting text in a UITextField when using leftView

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextfield, ios6

Currently I am setting a `leftView` with an image and I am finding that the image is too close to the text input view (which in this case is the standard `UITextField` text input view). Is there a way to shift the frame of the text input view slightly so as to increase the distance between it and the `leftView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to modify the `frame` property for the `UIImageView` you're assigning to the `UITextField`'s `leftView`.

For example you might be able to do something like this:

```
UIImageView *someImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage"]];

// add 5 points to each side of the frame while keeping the same center point
someImageView.frame = CGRectInset(someImageView.frame, -5, 0);

textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
textField.leftView = someImageView;
```

Note that you *may* also need to modify the `UIImageView`'s `contentMode` property to get the desired effect (e.g. you can use `UIViewContentModeLeft` to left-align the image or `UIViewContentModeCenter` to center-align it).

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing. Thanks.